# Specializing std::hash for std::array

Tags: c++, array, hash-map

I want to have an `std::unordered_map` which uses arrays as keys. As long as a type has an `operator==` and an `std::hash` it can be used as a key.

Here is my `std::hash<std::array>`

```
template<class T, size_t N> 
struct std::hash<std::array<T, N>> {
    auto operator() (const std::array<T, N>& key) const {
        std::hash<T> hasher;
        size_t result = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            result = result * 31 + hasher(key[i]); // ??
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

I copied the multiply by 31 from somewhere. An example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) uses `<<` and `^`. I don't know which is better or how to apply the cppreference example to an array.

```
// cppreference example
template<> struct hash<S>
    {
        typedef S argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
        {
            result_type const h1 ( std::hash<std::string>{}(s.first_name) );
            result_type const h2 ( std::hash<std::string>{}(s.last_name) );
            return h1 ^ (h2 << 1); // or use boost::hash_combine (see Discussion)
        }
    };
```

It seems to work. All of the code compiles and the return values for `std::hash<key_type>` seem ok to me.

```
using key_type = std::array<int, 2>;
using hash_type = std::hash<key_type>;
using map_type = std::unordered_map<key_type, int>;

map_type map; // compiles
hash_type hasher; // compiles

int main() {
    // test return values of std::hash<key_type>
    for(int y = -2; y < 3; ++y) {
        for(int x = -2; x < 3; ++x) {
            std::cout << hasher({x, y}) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The values printed from this code are:

```
18446744073709551552 18446744073709551583 18446744073709551614 29 60 
18446744073709551553 18446744073709551584 18446744073709551615 30 61 
18446744073709551554 18446744073709551585 0 31 62 
18446744073709551555 18446744073709551586 1 32 63 
18446744073709551556 18446744073709551587 2 33 64
```

I'm not sure what makes a good hash function for `std::unordered_map`, so I'd appreciate any feedback on how to make this hash function better.

Comment: Some worthwhile reading about choice of constants in [an answer to *Why is boost::hash_combine the best way to combine hash-values?*](//stackoverflow.com/a/35991300).

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 5 → 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Implicit assumption:

It looks like you make an implicit assumption here:

```
std::hash<T> hasher;
```

making it non-member means that you assume `std::hash` is not allowed to have any state, which is false. It is not required to be monostate, so the hasher should be a member of the specialization.

#### When the assumption can bite you?

Consider this implementation in pseudocode:

```
store `std::map<T, counter_type>` as data member.
on every call to hash an array, for each element:
    result = result * 31 + map[elem]
```

Imagine that `counter_type` is just a counter, e.g. each unique instance gives a unique number, in incremental order. If you would leave the `std::hash<T>` as local, this would happen:

```
on every call to hash an array for each element:
    result = result * 31 + 0 //or whatever counter starts from
```

So it would degrade any unordered container.

### Example version

Example version uses specific operators to the specific class, whereas your code is generic. So, I guess your version should be fine with the applied change described above.

### 31

I've seen it being used in "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch. I believe he described it as prime which is closest to the power of two, which has positive impact on overflow (e.g. one number won't be repeated for pretty long time). I don't have any maths to back this up, but I believe the direction is right.

Answer (score 3):

### What is a "good" hash function?

The requirement of a hash function is that it always produces the same value for a given key (in the same instance of the program) and a *good* hash function should produce each output with equal probability.

Your function achieves this (multiplying by a prime such as 31 is a well-known way of combining hash values to reduce collisions caused by different permutations of the same values).

However, it's up to you to decide whether the hash inputs in *your* application have a random distribution, or whether they have some pattern that may perturb the output distribution from the hash function.

Can you use your mental reasoning to force a collision?  `{1, 0}` and `{0, 31}` might do it, for example.  Can you think of any reason why your code might produce collisions more often than by independent chance?

### Style points

The code is neat and clear.  It might be an idea to allow an alternative to `std::hash<T>` to be supplied by the caller, just as `std::unordered_map` itself allows a user-supplied hasher.  This may be useful with `char*` strings, for example.

You could simplify the loop, as `std::array` supports range-based `for`:

```
    for (const auto& element: key) {
        result = result * 31 + hasher(element);
    }
```

### More tests

It's good that you've provided a test suite.  Consider whether you could add more tests - at least one test with an element type other than `int` and at least least one with different array lengths (you should probably include a test for `std::array<char, 1>` as a boundary case, for example).

### Alternatives

Boost provides a `hash()` function that accepts built-in (i.e. C-style) arrays, so you might be able to `reinterpret_cast` the `std::array`.  I've never tried this, but I don't see why it wouldn't work...

Comment: the only non-static member of `std::array<>` is allowed to be the C array itself, so probably casting it should be okay, it would even dodge all of the alignment issues.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing and creating a good one is a complex subject that I will let other more educated people delve into:

This seems reasonable to my uneducated eye:

```
template<class T, size_t N> 
struct std::hash<std::array<T, N>> {
    auto operator() (const std::array<T, N>& key) const {
        std::hash<T> hasher;
        size_t result = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            result = result * 31 + hasher(key[i]); // ??
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

You use a prime `31` as the multiplicand. Which seems reasonable.

The one thing I may change was the seed value `result = 0;`. Currently an array with a single value has the same hash as that single value. I would just generate a seed value (make it a large prime for fun `144451`).

To use the `return h1 ^ (h2 << 1)` in your class just do the following.

```
template<class T, size_t N> 
struct std::hash<std::array<T, N>> {
    auto operator() (const std::array<T, N>& key) const {
        std::hash<T> hasher;
        size_t result = 0;   // I would still seed this.
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            result = (result << 1) ^ hasher(key[i]); // ??
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```